# Changing pagination using pagerFactory

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I hope you can help. I am trying to change how a pagination is displayed using the cycle.js plugin.

At the moment this function counts how many slides there are and numbers them accordingly, I need to remove these and replace the numbers for words.

This is the original function:

```
$(function() {

$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollHorz',
    timeout:  0,
    prev:    '#prev',
    next:    '#next',
    pager:   '.ms-links',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
});

function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
    var s = idx > 3 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
    return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
};
```

});

And I have tried this thinking it might work:

```
$(function() {

$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollHorz',
    timeout:  0,
    prev:    '#prev',
    next:    '#next',
    pager:   '.ms-links',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
});

function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
        var s = idx > 3 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
            var strcat = "";
            if idx = 1 { strcat = "News";}
            if idx = 2 { strcat = "Blogs";}
            if idx = 3 { strcat = "MSTV";}
            if idx = 4 { strcat = "Publications";}

        return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+(strcat)+'</a></li>';
    };
```

});

But that just breaks it - I'm not a jQuery expert so it may be something really simple. But basically I have 4 sliders, there will never be any more than 4 and need to name them 'News, Blogs, TV and Publications'

Any advice on how to get this to work would be REALLY appreciated, thank you!

Gav

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry pal, thanks so much for your reply, I did manage to fix this in the end.